# How should I change elements content on ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to change the text in some elements on ace editor with an `input type=range` but when I try to write again, the editor returns to a previous value before it was modified with javascript

```js
var editordiv = document.getElementById("editor");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
var elem;
editordiv.onmousedown=function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains("ace_numeric")) elem=e.target;
}
function changeElement(range){
    if(elem) elem.textContent=range.value; //not changing correctly editor content
}
```

```css
#editor{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.ace_constant {
    pointer-events:auto !important;
}
#range{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.2.3/noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor">var i=30;
var j=70;</div>
<input type="range" id="range" oninput="changeElement(this)">
```

**How can I change the value correctly of a number and keep the history in ace editor?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the solution I found is a little more complicated than expected:

```
var elem = undefined;
var rn = undefined;
function changeElement(range){
    if(rn) editor.session.replace(rn,range.value); //input value into range text
}
editor.on("mousemove",function(e){
    if(e.domEvent.target.classList.contains("ace_numeric")){
        elem = e.domEvent.target;
        var position = e.getDocumentPosition();
        var token = editor.session.getTokenAt(position.row, position.column+1);
        if(token.value.match(/^[+-]?[.\d]+$/)) //token value is a number
            rn = new Range(position.row, token.start, position.row, token.start+elem.textContent.length); //range of text in editor
    }
});
```

Instead of replacing the dom element, save the range position onmousedown and replace the text when the input range changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the contents of the editor through the editors interface, not by modifying the dom within the editor. One, slightly messy, way to do this is with `editor.replace`. You can tweak the regex/parameters as you see fit:

```js
var editordiv = document.getElementById("editor");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

function changeElement (range) {
  editor.replace('=' + range.value + ';', {needle: /=\d+;/});
}
```

```css
#editor{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.ace_constant {
    pointer-events:auto !important;
}
#range{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.2.3/noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor">var i=80;</div>
<input type="range" id="range" oninput="changeElement(this)">
```

Comment: but that is going to replace all the numbers in the text or the lines that look the same

Comment: so is targetting `ace_numeric` can you better define your criteria for replacing? You can alternately use an ace Range to do this and target the 1at row/column

Comment: ok, I'm sorry about that I edited the code until it was too simple. The constant under the mouse is supposed to be modified by the input, in this case after mousedown event. Changed it back.